# Creating Login/Password in C# (compare List<> to string)

Tags: c#, string, wcf, list

Hello im trying to create a login using wcf but somehow looks like my program dont work as I wanted ;(

```
 public class UserService : IUserService
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<UserInfo> GetUserInformation()
    {
        QuizDBEntities contex = new QuizDBEntities();
        var UserInfo = from a in contex.UserInfoes select a;

        return UserInfo.ToList();

    }

}
```

I created

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string username = TextBox1.Text;
            string password = TextBox2.Text;
            UserService vs = new UserService();
            List<UserInfo> alfa = new List<UserInfo>();
 }
```

I used few foreach/if loop but every time I do something wrong and my list act like its empty ( I tried grindwiev and did get all  data ;( ) Anyone can help me and give hint how can I compare List to login/password ?

Comment: You may have written a service, but you're not using it like one.  `UserService vs = new UserService();` is simply creating a new instance of the class.  Did you add a service reference to the UserService?

Comment: Im using {public interface IUserService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<UserInfo> GetUserInformation();
}}

Comment: I could tell that by the posted code for `UserService`.  Do you have a reference to `UserService`, or do you have a **service reference** to it?  They are not the same thing.  It appears in your posted code that you're trying to access the service directly, and that is not how SOAP web services are accessed.  They are accessed through a proxy, and if you use Add Service Reference to add the service, VS will create the proxy for you automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A WCF service isn't actually a service until it's hosted somewhere (IIS, self-hosted, etc).  Simply adding the attributes `[ServiceContract]` and `[OperationContract]` do not magically make it a service.

SOAP Web services like WCF are not directly accessed by the client - the client goes through a proxy to interact with the service.  This proxy can be generated automatically by Visual Studio through either Add Service Reference or the command line svcutil.exe.  An easy way to do this is to create a new WCF Service Application - this will be hosted in IIS.  There are different (and in my opinion better) ways to host the service, but for simplicity and sake of illustration we'll go with this one.

So let's assume you have a WCF service application up and running, and it has the code you posted above.  You could then choose Add Service Reference in the VS Solution Explorer to add a service reference to your service.  This will generate a proxy for you to use.  The name of the proxy is usually `UserServiceClient` (i.e., Visual Studio adds `Client` to the end).

To call a method in your service with this proxy, you would do this:

```
UserServiceClient proxy = new UserServiceClient();
List<UserInfo> users = proxy.GetUserInformation;
```

This would give you a list of all the users in your database.  You would probably want to either markup the `UserInfo` entity as a DataContract, or create a new class that has the properties in it as a DataContract - your current code doesn't do anything to set the properties it has in it, and services themselves don't do anything with properties (not to mention your code isn't setting any values for them anyway).

Now for your other question - "how can I compare List to login/password"?  In a nutshell, you can't.  Your `List<UserInfo>` is a list of `UserInfo` objects, and you're attempting to compare a string to this list.  That won't work.

What you could do, however, is create another method in your service that would accept a username and a password and return that user's information if it is found.  It might look something like below, but first let's make a DataContract to hold the UserInfo (basically moving the DataMembers from the service to a separate class:

```
[DataContract]
public class UserInformation
{

    [DataMember]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public UserInformation GetUser(string userName, string password)
{

    UserInformation user = new UserInformation();

    using (QuizDBEntities context = new QuizDBEntities())
    {

        user = (from a in context.UserInfoes
                where a.UserName == userName && a.Password == password
                select new UserInformation() {
                    Login = a.UserName,
                    Password = a.Password,
                    Type = a.Type,
                    ID = a.ID}).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    return user;
}
```

The  `UserInformation` class contains the DataMembers you originally had in your service.  The LINQ query selects the user that has the matching UserName and Password and populates the `UserInformation` class (property names are conjecture as I don't know what your `UserInfo` entity looks like).  The `SingleOrDefault()` at the end selects one matching result, or if no match is found returns the default value - which in this case will be null.

You could then use it like this:

```
UserServiceClient proxy = new UserServiceClient();
UserInformation user = proxy.GetUser("someName", "somePassword");
proxy.Close();

if (user == null)
{
    // No match was found, so do something
}
else
{
    // Match was found, so proceed with what you were doing
}
```

All of the above is primarily for illustration purposes, but you should be able to adapt to your program's needs.  I would also suggest Googling for some good tutorials on how to create and host a WCF service.